# Trying to pass JSON object REACTJS not working

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I am starting to get involved in ReactJS, I am trying to pass to my tag a JSON object so then I can show it in the UI but it keeps saying that element is not found. Any help on this? Or why the props object is not having the JSON object? Thanks in advance

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="img-container">
            <img src="{this.props.placementImage}" />
        </div>
    );
  }
});

var MP = [
    {
        id: "MP1001",
        placementImage: "https://www.aexp-static.com/intl/uk/rwd/images/UKHP_CM_promo_3.png",
        dts: "forever",
        dte: "forever",
        status: "",
        isDefault: false
    }
];

ReactDOM.render(
        <CommentBox mp={MP}/>,
        document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things:

1. You're passing an array as the `mp` prop, but then attempting to access it like an object.
2. You need to remove the quotes from the `<img>` src attribute:
3. You need to access the actual `mp` prop

For reference, I've created a JSBin example from your code that fixes these issues: http://jsbin.com/bohoqa/edit?html,js,output

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="img-container">
            <img src={this.props.mp.placementImage} />
        </div>
    );
  }
});

var MP = [
    {
        id: "MP1001",
        placementImage: "https://www.aexp-static.com/intl/uk/rwd/images/UKHP_CM_promo_3.png",
        dts: "forever",
        dte: "forever",
        status: "",
        isDefault: false
    }
];

ReactDOM.render(
        <CommentBox mp={MP[0]}/>,
        document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought as I was reading that the object will be available in the props reactJS object but seems that I even have to do reference to props.mp. Thanks for the information

Comment: You could use the JSX spread operator to achieve exactly what you want. 
<CommentCox { ...MP[0] } />
See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html for more.

Comment: I am trying for the moment no to depend on some external libraries and rather to do everything manually using javascript. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<img src="{this.props.placementImage}" />
```

to

```
<img src={this.props.mp[index].placementImage} />
```

You have to pass them as objects {} not "{}"

edit: I did not notice it was an array

Comment: That was my issue, beside that the .mp was missing, I thought it was already in the props object. Thanks